# iText: HTML to PDF conversion, css issue

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using the following css and expecting a drop shadow around the divs in the pdf. However, it doesn't appear in the generated pdf using itext. It does show up when the html is viewed in the browser (chrome)

```
.dropShadow {
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px #000;
    box-shadow:5px 5px #000;
}
.dropShadow table { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-spacing:15px;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
} 
.dropShadow tr, .dropShadow td {
    padding:2px;
}
```

any ideas why this could occur?

Comment: Which itext html to pdf tool do you use? `HTMLWorker`? `XMLWorker`? Or pdfHtml?

Comment: "box-shadow" hasn't been supported in iText7's `pdfHTML` yet.

Comment: I am using pdfHTML. Would it work if I use HTMLWorker or XMLWorker?

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you clarify if background-color is supported in itext7? Is there a list of supported css styles published anywhere?

Comment: It would not work in the older and deprecated HTMLWorker or XMLWorker. Adding `box-shadow` to iText 7's pdfHTML sounds like a feature request. Do you have a support contract? If yes, contact iText directly, that's the fastest way to get help.